# onFocusChange including children?

Tags: android

Assume that I have a simple full-screen ConstraintLayout, with a few EditTexts and TextViews in the middle.

Is it possible to know whether one of those views is in focus? What I'm trying to achieve is basically a blanket onFocusChangeListener for all children of a layout.

I've tried assigning a listener to the ConstraintLayout, but it only fires if I tap on the layout itself, outside of those EditTexts.

I could simply assign a listener for each individual element in the UI, but what if I have hundreds?

<sub>(I could simply loop through all of them, but please assume I can't)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

You could attach a global listener to your [ViewTreeObserver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#getViewTreeObserver()) with [addOnGlobalFocusChangeListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewTreeObserver#addOnGlobalFocusChangeListener(android.view.ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalFocusChangeListener)). Something like:

```
view.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalFocusChangeListener(
    new OnGlobalFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalFocusChanged(View prevFocus, View newFocus) {
            // Do stuff here
        }
    }
);
```